# Condition for selecting an object in body: JSON.stringify ()

Tags: javascript, json

I ask for your help in writing the conditions for selecting an object in JSON.stringify ().
How can i do this?

```
this.props.a > 7;
 this.props.b > 7

    onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.x(this.state.y);

    const user1 = {
            name: "John", 
            age: 30
        };
           const user2 = {
            name: "Vasya", 
            age: 27
        }

    fetch('URL', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        },

 body:JSON.stringify (How can I write something with a similar meaning 
 this.props.a>7 ? USER1:USER2 )
        });
}
```

Comment: You'd write exactly that (but with the correct capitalization: `body: JSON.stringify(this.props.a > 7 ? user1 : user2)`). What problem are you running into?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
body: ( this.props.a>7 ? JSON.stringify(USER1) : JSON.stringify(USER2) )
```

Comment: Your option body: ( this.props.a>7 ? JSON.stringify(USER1) : JSON.stringify(USER2) )  not right.